# Passing URL from Chrome Extension to executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Very noob question I'm sure, but struggling with this one. Trying to get the current tab URL passed to the executeScript external script.

I've tried sending a message, but the message doesn't arrive. Not sure what's going wrong.

**popup.js**

```
function onWindowLoad() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "getPagesSource.js"
  }, function() {
 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(null, {url:tabs[0].url});
  });  
});
}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

**getPagesSource.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert('message '+message.url);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  ...
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Comment: getPagesSource.js is a content script so it runs in the context of the web page and you can get its URL using the standard DOM methods e.g. `location.href` inside getPagesSource.js - no need for messaging.

Comment: So Simple! Thanks so much